# How to get PHP site live on amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have already installed ubuntu14, lamp, phpmyadmin on the EC2 instance. The site is running fine with the public dsn:

> http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

Now I need to make it live for original domain like

> http://example.com

I did not register `example.com`  through amazon aws, but through the separate domain service provider. In Route 53, I added a hosted zone with `example.com` that created two record sets. One with NS and one with SOA. I noted NS, name server/Delegation Set provided by `amazone route 53` and replaced the existing name server from registrar from where I purchased domain.

How to i link `Route 53 hosted zone` with my `ec2 apache www`

What is next step? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS Route 53. You need to create an `A` type record in you hosted zone. Click on Create Record Set and in the right panel use the following values:

```
Name: <leave blank>
Type: A - IPv4 address
Value: <your elastic ip>
```

Then hit Create button.

If you want www.example.com create another record filling field Name with www.

Comment: Ok, so where can i do this in aws console?

Comment: DO i need to bind elastic ip with my running/configured ec2 instance?

Comment: So where can i do this in aws console?

Comment: Error: The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format. Should i add elastic/public ip that i have attched with my instance?

Comment: I thought that was posible. Anyway two options add an elastic ip (best) or in Type value, use a CNAME record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just point your domain to amazon public IP.For example, login to your domain registrar and edit A record and add your public ip in points to.Thant's it. :)